# Angular 7 Sweet alert show dynamic table

Tags: javascript, angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweet alert 2 with Angular 7, And i'm trying to display dynamic table.

Json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "age": 23
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Daniel",
    "age": 18
  }
]
```

I've tried to use *ngFor but unfortunately,it's not working.

```
Swal({
  position: 'center',
  type: 'info',
  title: `Class Information`,
  html: `<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>`,
});
```

Alternative i'm trying to display my own component.

```
  Swal({
      position: 'center',
      type: 'info',
      title: `Class Information`,
      html: `<class-component [inputClassInformation]="classInformationJson"></class-component>`
    });
```

This is not working as well.

My goal is display the following pop-up :
[image]

Comment: is it possible using Sweet alert 2?

Comment: It's been a while since I post this question.. I ended up using an angular material table since sweet alert wasn't the right choice for me. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: okay no issues but have you idea about this problem, i really need help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use ngx-sweetalert2 for Angular 7 to show show dynamic table

[ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2)

```html
<swal title="Fill the form, rapidly">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</swal>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay! 
this is still not working, can you please post stackblitz example.

Comment: @AmitBaranes you need to use ngx-sweetalert2 https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2

Comment: I figure it out ! 
the wrapper div should contain  *swalPartial.
thank you !

Comment: can you please share the stackblitz demo i have tried to solve this issues.